# Odd one's out (sequence)

Tags: geometry, number-sequence, sequence

Once upon a time, there was a curious mathematician named Friedrich. One day, while exploring a new area of mathematics, he stumbled upon an intriguing sequence of numbers:
0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7...

Friedrich was determined to figure out how this sequence was generated. He spent countless hours studying the pattern and experimenting with different formulas, but to no avail. Can you help our dear Friedrich?

Comment: Nice first question! Did you create this yourself?

Comment: is there a typo here?  0, 1, 2, 2, **4**, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7...

Comment: Time to add a hint?